# Is it possible to add background color fade(animation) on ListView item Style?

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, uwp

I have several `Windows.UI.Xaml.Style`'s that work with a "StyleSelector":

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyleSelector>
        <vm:FlagStyleSelector>
            <vm:FlagStyleSelector.NormalStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2"/>
                    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="0"/>
                    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="0"/>
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="10"/>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"  .. how to fade this out over 5 seconds?
                </Style>
            </vm:FlagStyleSelector.NormalStyle>
            <vm:FlagStyleSelector.OtherStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    ...
                    ...
                </Style>
            </vm:FlagStyleSelector.OtherStyle>
        </vm:FlagStyleSelector>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyleSelector>
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Is it possible to add something like a `StoryBoard` with `Animation` that fades the `Background` color out over 5 seconds for a style like `NormalStyle` above?

I use MVVM, and therefore no code-behind.

EDIT:

I would like the color fade target to be the `Bakground` property on the `Style`. The `ListView` is binded to an `ObservableCollection<T>`, the trigger for the animation is when a current item `T` is updated in the collection, or when a new item is added:

```
<Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"  .. how to fade this out over 5 seconds?
```

Comment: What makes you think that animations like this should be implemented in the view model...? It shouldn't. Implementing something that is view related in the code-behind doesn't break the MVVM pattern. Implementing view related stuff in the view model does though.

Comment: How do you want to trigger the animation? Status or something else? What's the expected behavior you want to get?

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT , the status or value of a column